Old cartoon where a boy is trying to find a monster that flew away
So, from what I can remember, this was a cartoon about a boy who liked monsters, and had discovered ways of looking after them. He has a powerful winged one that lives in his room, potentially in his closet, and somehow escapes and flies away. He spends a very long time trying to track it down because he’s concerned for it, and, if I’m remembering right, at some point he begins looking after its offspring? I feel like the main character had help from friends too.
This would have been airing over 10 years ago, I want to say on public UK TV too, so probably on one of the Freeview cartoon channels. I’ve tried googling the show and can’t seem to find it for the life of me.
Can someone identify this show?

Was the animation 2D (hand-drawn) or 3D (computer-generated)?
